# Spring Form: The Request sent by the client was syntactally incorrect

Tags: java, spring, forms, jsp

I have the following jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

      <form:form action="save_event" modelAttribute="eventForm" method="post">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Create Event</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                <label for="eventNameInput">Name:</label>
                <form:input id="eventNameInput" class="form-control" type="text" path="eventName" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                <label for="eventStartInput">Start:</label>
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <form:input id="eventStartInput" class="form-control" type="text" path="startDate" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                <label for="eventEndInput">End:</label>
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                    <form:input id="eventEndInput" class="form-control" type="text" path="endDate" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                <label for="eventDescInput">Description:</label>
                <form:textarea id="eventDescInput" class="form-control" path="description"></form:textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset" />
    </div>

    </form:form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            sideBySide: true,
            format: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"
        });
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
            sideBySide: true,
            format: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And the following Controller:

```
@Controller
public class EventCreateController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/create_event", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createEvent(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("eventForm", new EventForm());
        return "create_event";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/save_event", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String eventSubmit(@ModelAttribute("eventForm") EventForm form, Model model) {

        List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
        model.addAttribute("eventList", eventList);

        return "redirect:/welcome";
    }

}
```

But whenever submitting the form I get the error:
The request by the client sent was syntactically incorrect.

I am sending the form via post and expecting the form via post. I am adressing "/save_event" and I am expecting the result at "/save_event".

Some ideas?

EDIT: Here is the application-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.afterguard.sailplanner.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And the web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
            version="3.0">
  <display-name>SailPlanner</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>sailplanner</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sailplanner</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/users</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/create_event</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/save_event</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Please provide `EventForm` class and request body which is send to server (Chrome: F12 - network tab).

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the action be just `/save_event` instead of `${context}/save_event.jsp`?

1. Prefixing the context should be taken care automatically as you are using `form:form`, i.e. form taglib.
2. Why the `.jsp` suffix?

Comment: This doesn't work. Without jsp he does not know where the resource is being found.
And with the code {save_event.jsp} instead of {${context}/save_event.jsp} I get the same error, as before...

Comment: But, you are posting to the controller method, not to a JSP, right?

Comment: Try to add a debug point, or a log line in your controller, just in case it's getting into the controller method, but not able to find the view. As Ankur says, you may need to provide prefix and suffix for the JSPs.

Comment: No, he is not even calling the controller. I think there is a problem with resolving the {welcome} to the controller with the {@RequestMapping("/welcome")}

Comment: Ok, now everything is working WITHOUT the .jsp, but I still get the old error with the updated question (everything adjusted as it is now)...

Comment: Basically, you shouldn't be redirecting or posting to views directly. Also, you should have view resolvers. If you are using Spring Boot, configuring a view reslover is as simple as providing just a couple of properties in application.properties. You might first like to go through these basics in a little more details, if you aren't familiar with these.

Comment: I found the problem... It was missing "BindingResult result" in the function of the saveEvent.

Answer (score 0):

RequestMapping value should be same as the form's action. Use form tag in place of form:form and don't declare .jsp extension in your form action or in controller, just define a **InternalResourceViewResolver** in your applicationContext.xml

**CODE:**

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

**EDIT :** Replace */pages/* to your view pages location.

**jsp:**

```
<form action="save_event" modelAttribute="eventForm" method="post">

  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Create Event</h4>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class EventCreateController {

@RequestMapping(value="/save_event", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String eventSubmit(@ModelAttribute("eventForm") EventForm form, Model model) {

    List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
    model.addAttribute("eventList", eventList);

    return "redirect:/welcome";
  }

}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: I have no applicationContext. Where do I put this and how to configure it (and where)?
But I have an application-servlet.xml

Comment: OP: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: where are you defining other beans?
If it's in application-servlet.xml, then put the specified bean in your application-servlet.xml.

Comment: I am posting this result according to SPRING MVC

Comment: I asked to Don, probably he is using Spring Boot, that's why he doesn't have any configuration files.

Comment: I have the application-servlet.xml and there is one bean configured, the one you are talking about.
But he can't resolve {/welcome} to {/welcome.jsp} for example.

Comment: Just edit your question again and show us your application-servlet.xml so that we can provide you the exact solution.

Comment: Have you modified the form tag and its action also ?
<form action="save_event" method="post">

Comment: <context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

Add these lines to your web.xml

Comment: contextConfigLocation is important and just specify your application-servlet.xml path in its param-value attribute

Comment: and one more thing just remove servlet mapping from your web.xml, Spring MVC autometically handles it.

Comment: Without the servlet mappings I receive "The requested Resource is not available"

Comment: add ContextLoaderListener in your web.xml, and if this solution is working for you please accept and upvote this answer so that in future others can refer it. Thanks

Comment: and add servlets mapping if you want it doesn't affect your code.